# SSIS - Serialize/Lock a package

Tags: ssis, etl, netezza

Long story short, I need to create a sequence in Netezza using SSIS.

I plan to create a generic package that will look up some tables and based on the natural key and the source, it will either return the surrogate key if existing or create a new key and return it back to the calling SSIS package.

This package will be called by multiple SSIS packages one for each source.  My issue is they could all be running at the same time and call this package concurrently which could cause uniqueness issues in the surrogate key.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a Netezza sequence? You're just making things difficult (and non scaleable) for yourself here.

Comment: Nick-  SSIS is just for orchestration.  Under the hood, we will be using Netezza sequence anyways.  My problem is that I have multiple sources (one package/job for each source) and I want to minimize the refactoring and replicating the same logic of creating the keys in all the packages.  This is a near term solution as there is a parallel effort to migrate to AWS.  We will have to figure out something different once that solution is finalized.  I agree with your comment that this is not scalable and this table will be very hot.  But that is the best I could think of. Thanks much for your time

Comment: There's no problem with the same package being called simultaneously by other packages, if under the covers it uses a sequence. A sequence guarantees you'll get a new number. What would actually be better, if possible, is if you create a stored proc that took a table name and natural key and returned an existing or new surrogate key. Then you can call the proc from every package. rather than having to call an entire subpackage (which have other issues like not being logged, additional overhead when running out of process and things like that)

Comment: That is what I was thinking too Nick.  If package1 calls the child package and simultaneously package2 calls, it will go into 30 s wait.  Package 1 might finish and then package 3 calls it before the 30 s wait time of Package 2 finishes.  This way, theoretically, package 2 might never get its turn.  I will try the stored procedure method and try to simulate the real life scenario in the POC.  I will keep you guys posted.  Thanks again for your time.  PS:  I dont need to return any keys to the calling package.  I just need to update the table and they will look up as a part of their process.

Answer (score 0):

Create the child (lookup) package and then create a SQL Agent Job with a single step that executes the package. Then your parent package can execute the job, instead of the package directly. The SQL Agent will take care of "locking" the package, as a job can only have a single instance running.

You'll probably need to build in some kind of wait mechanism. You can query `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` to determine if the job is running or not.

I recently built a package that does almost exactly what you're trying to do. Here's what it ended up looking like:
[image]

In the first Execute SQL step I'm getting the JobId and step names. The proc being called uses the following query (I pass in the @JobName):

```
SELECT @JobId = job_id 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE name = @JobName
```

Then `Is the job running` Execute SQL task executes the following query to check if the job is running:

```
DECLARE @JobId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @JobId = ?

SELECT 
Running = 
CASE 
    WHEN start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND stop_execution_date IS NULL 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity 
WHERE job_id = @JobId
```

I save the value to a variable, and then enable and disable the appropriate paths afterwards. If the job is running, I wait 30 seconds and then the `Wait while job is running` loops restarts and checks the job activity status again.

The 1 second wait was put in to give the db engine enough time to update the job activity table. My package was failing because it was performing the check too quickly and thought it was ok to initiate the next execution of the job. By pausing momentarily we're able to get accurate results when checking the job activity status.

Once the package gets to `Start Job Step` it executes the following query to kick off the job:

```
DECLARE @step VARCHAR(100)
,@Job VARCHAR(100)

SET @step = ?
SET @Job = ?

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @job, @step_name = @step
```

If your case you wouldn't need to specify the step, since your lookup package job will just have a single step in it.

Comment: Aaron-  Thanks a lot for your solution.  I will try this out and let you know.  Conceptually, it sounds perfect to me for what I am looking for.  Thanks much.  Will keep you posted

Comment: You can't pass variables around jobs though... (i.e. you can't return a surrogate key). Also.... a 30 second wait is not going to scale of you're loading 1,000 records and trying to lookup / generate a key.